# glassfish and restfull webservice exception

Tags: java, web-services

I'm quite new to java webservices. I deployed a restfull web service on glassfish. Web service works well for about 10 or 20 hours and then the system doesn't respond. Below is the exception thrown everytime the service is called (After the system breaks). Please tell me why this exception is thrown.
Thanks

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkClosed(StatementImpl.java:458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1418)
    at datamodel.Question_Data_Factory.getFilteredQData(Question_Data_Factory.java:44)
```

Comment: Check your jdbc driver timeout.  The default(for the one we used) was 12 hours.  So if it went inactive, it closed.  And no new connections could be opened.

Comment: Are you using a datasource or are you managing the opening and closing of the connections?

Comment: I am managing the opening and closing of the connections

Comment: @Thomas yes you are correct. problem was with the timeout. thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason was jdbc driver connection closes automatically when it is idle for a long time. setting conncetTimeout to 0 resolved the problem